# Django to work with south requires MySQLdb

Tags: django, mysql-python

I am following the [django instruction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) to learn django in eclipse.

I came to the part of running cmd

```
python manage.py migrate
```

and it complains about unknown command migrate.

Googled. Knew that it requires South module to be included. I downloaded/installed south, and added 'south' in the INSTALLED_APPS.

I ran the command again, this time it complains

```
import MySQLdb as Database
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

So I looked for MySQLdb, only to find that there is none for python 3.

I could not find anything useful. So what do you do to make django to work with mysql?

I know there're other connectors around, but I am trying to follow the django tutorial and it seems that 'migrate' cmd must use 'south' and 'south' must use MySQLdb(?)

--- update ---
Here is the DB settings in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

I suspect 'ENGINE' has to be something else, but I failed to find enough information online to figure it out...

Comment: Why not just use sqlite3 instead, you won't have to install anything on your dev machine?

Comment: I will, in the end, use a proper DB anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to any database you want MySQL or postgresql or sqlite etc for your django app. South uses the default database engine from your django setting [DATABASES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases). As stated [here](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/databaseapi.html#accessing-the-api)

> South automatically exposes the correct set of database API operations
>   as south.db.db; it detects which database backend you’re using from
>   your Django settings file.

Comment: do i need to add more configuration for south? I have updated OP for the settings I have..

Comment: Check this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE-ENGINE) for possible `ENGINE` values.